# Trouble in installing Font::TTF module

Tags: perl, module, circos

I failed to install the module through `cpan Font::TTF`. 
I'm on strawberry perl 5.24, windows 8 32bit.

```
C:\Users\user>cpan
Loading internal null logger. Install Log::Log4perl for logging messages

There seems to be running another CPAN process (pid 5860).  Contacting...
Other job not responding. Shall I overwrite the lockfile 'C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\.lock
'? (Y/n) [y]

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v2.11)
Enter 'h' for help.


cpan> o conf build_dir_reuse 0
    build_dir_reuse    [0]
commit: wrote 'C:\Strawberry\perl\lib/CPAN/Config.pm'


cpan> o conf commit
commit: wrote 'C:\Strawberry\perl\lib/CPAN/Config.pm'


cpan> exit
Lockfile removed.


C:\Users\user>cpan Font::TTF
Loading internal null logger. Install Log::Log4perl for logging messages
CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.211)
Database was generated on Fri, 15 Jul 2016 06:47:48 GMT

Running install for module 'Font::TTF'
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.95)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.069)
Checksum for C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\sources\authors\id\M\MH\MHOSKEN\Font-TTF-  1.05.tar.
gz ok
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v2.06)
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.2304)
CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.62)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta::Requirements loaded ok (v2.140)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v1.4417)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150005)
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20160507)
Configuring M/MH/MHOSKEN/Font-TTF-1.05.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Font::TTF
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  MHOSKEN/Font-TTF-1.05.tar.gz
  C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for M/MH/MHOSKEN/Font-TTF-1.05.tar.gz
  MHOSKEN/Font-TTF-1.05.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe -- OK
Running make test
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness"   "-
e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')"   t/
*.t
t/tags.t ..... Can't locate Font/TTF/OTTags.pm in @INC (you may need to   install
the Font::TTF::OTTags module) (@INC contains: C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\Font-TTF-1.
05-8DWSyh\blib\lib C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\Font-TTF-1.05-8DWSyh\blib\arch  C:/Stra
wberry/perl/site/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/lib .) at
t/tags.t line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/tags.t line 5.
t/tags.t ..... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 6/6 subtests
t/ttfcopy.t .. Can't locate Font/TTF/Font.pm in @INC (you may need to install th
e Font::TTF::Font module) (@INC contains: C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\Font-TTF-  1.05-8
DWSyh\blib\lib C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\Font-TTF-1.05-8DWSyh\blib\arch C:/Strawber
ry/perl/site/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/lib .) at t/tt
fcopy.t line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/ttfcopy.t line 5.
t/ttfcopy.t .. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 4/4 subtests

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/tags.t   (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 6 tests but ran 0.
t/ttfcopy.t (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 4 tests but ran 0.
Files=2, Tests=0,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.05 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.05 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 2/2 test programs. 0/0 subtests failed.
dmake.exe:  Error code 130, while making 'test_dynamic'
  MHOSKEN/Font-TTF-1.05.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports MHOSKEN/Font-TTF-1.05.tar.gz
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Font::TTF'.

C:\Users\user>
```

Comment: Please copy the text from the command line and paste it as a code into your question instead of the picture.

Comment: *head spins*

Even if you drop the image, please take a moment to clarify what you're asking. Include OS and relevant version numbers.

Comment: The "Has already" messages indicate we're not seeing the full picture. Please issue the following two commands from within `cpan`: `o conf build_dir_reuse 0` `o conf commit`. Then restart `cpan`, and try again. And please post the output as text, not an image.

Comment: can't reproduce on Strawberry Perl 5.20, Windows 7 64bit. Exit the cpan shell and try `cpan Font::TTF`. Which OS/Perl version are you on?

Comment: I've pasted the code, anybody can find what is wrong? I've aslo tried in my friends' computer, it turned out to be the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Jiang Bo, I was also getting the same problem with the latest Strawberry Perl version (5.24.0.1). I downgraded to 5.20.3.3 / 64bit and cpan installations work fine there.

Comment: I have then used activePerl instead of strawberryPerl, and it works well. Thank you!